# Key repeat in browser from python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, keyboard-events

*Note : I am pretty surprised I did not see that same question on this forum, if I missed it please link in comment :)*

I am writing a bot in python that would eventually be able to play a browser-based video game (HTML5 canvas game, not Flash). In order to do that I need to simulate the keyboard events from the python code.

I thought [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) would do the work, but unfortunately it seems the only way to repeat a key is to do `pyautogui.press(key)` in a loop, and it is not good at all for playing games as the move is not smooth at all.

I found some solutions for Windows, but I need a solution for macOSX.

Comment: If you want to automate something in a browser, you might want to look into selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I had the feeling that selenium would be a bit too heavy for my need, but I will consider it if there is nothing better, thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyobjc-framework-Quartz ? you'll probably need to detect the platform and write a small library layer in python specifically for mac using an objective c adapter to send CGKeyCode's